# My list of tasks only runs twice while it should run many times more

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to run a function over all rows, but instead of it running for each row at a time, I want it to run in parallel. The issue is that it seems to only run twice (while there are 217 products on the list) and it seems rows are picked randomly. I'm not sure why it's happening - the synchronous version works as intended.

The function makes an API call to a SOAP service that uses row data from WPF SfDataGrid. Maybe the API closes connection after so many requests? It's really hard to tell and I don't know how I could check it besides writing a ticket and waiting a week.

A part of event from which the function is called:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
using (var db = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=file:products.sqlite"))
{
    using (var client = new ApiOrdersPortTypeClient(binding, address))
    {
        db.Open();
        // run ScanProduct() on each row in a WPF SfDataGrid
        foreach (var row in ProductList.View.Records)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => ScanProduct(row, desiredDays, deliveryTime, client, db)));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

`ScanProduct()`:

```
private async Task ScanProduct(RecordEntry row, int desiredDays, int deliveryTime, ApiOrdersPortTypeClient client, SqliteConnection db)
{
    await db.OpenAsync();
    var selectedItem = (Product)row.Data;

    if (selectedItem.IsIgnored == true | selectedItem.IsInDelivery == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var pagesCount = await ApiRequests
            .GetOrdersPages(int.Parse(selectedItem.Id), desiredDays, client);

        var listSold = await ApiRequests
            .GetOrdersFromApi(int.Parse(selectedItem.Id), desiredDays, pagesCount);
        foat x = 100.0; // cut irrelevant stuff

        if (x > selectedItem.Stock)
        {
            using (var command = 
                new SqliteCommand($"UPDATE products_settings SET requires_purchase = 1,"
                + $" was_checked_with = {desiredDays},"
                + $"sold_amount = {listSold.Count}," 
                + $"average_daily = '{averageSales.ToString()}',"
                + $"average_delivery = '{x}'"
                + $"WHERE id = {selectedItem.Id};", db))
                {
                    await db.OpenAsync();
                    command.ExecuteReader();
                }
        } 
        else
        {
            using (var command2 = 
                new SqliteCommand($"UPDATE products_settings SET requires_purchase = 0,"
                + $"was_checked_with = {desiredDays},"
                + $"sold_amount = {listSold.Count},"
                + $"average_daily = '{averageSales.ToString()}',"
                + $"average_delivery = '{x}"
                + $"WHERE id = {selectedItem.Id};", db))
                {
                    await db.OpenAsync();
                    command2.ExecuteReader();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `ScanProduct` method not only makes SOAP requests but also updates your Sqlite database. Are you sure that your database [can handle concurrent updates](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Truth to be said, I didn't think about that as I never had any issue, it always seemed to me that the queries were made after the connection was closed.

Comment: The correct tool for this kind of work is the [TPL Dataflow Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). Any other solution will be suboptimal for one reason or another. For example if the SOAP call for the first product fails, do you really want to wait for the rest 216 SOAP calls to fail as well before being notified for the error? Because this is what happens if you use the simple and easy approach of `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` or `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ScanProduct(row, desiredDays, deliveryTime, client, db)));
```

`ScanProduct` is an asynchronous function, and thus needs to be awaited.

Each call to `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a `Task`, which will be awaited using `Task.WaitAll`, however, within each task, a call to `ScanProduct` will return **another** `Task`, which is **not** being awaited by `Task.WaitAll`.

The solution is to use an async lambda in combination with `Task.Run`, then in each case, the outer `Task` will not complete until `ScanProduct` has also completed.

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await ScanProduct(row, desiredDays, deliveryTime, client, db)));
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution, but I need to test it some more to be sure - now I need to restructure `ScanProduct` a bit. Your solution didn't _completely_ work but replacing `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `Task.Run` really did seem to do what I expected.

Comment: Your solution with `async () => await ScanProduct` is not different to the simple `ScanProduct`. In both cases the `Task.Factory.StartNew` is feeded with an async delegate, that doesn't understand. You should either [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) the returned `Task<Task>`, or use the `Task.Run` method that does the unwrapping automatically (because it understands async delegates).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That's interesting, thank you. The way Johnathan suggested did work as I expected though, with one culprit - UI hangs during `Task.WaitAll()`. The queries are a lot faster, but the UI now hangs. Fair trade off for me now, but I would appreciate a different solution.

Comment: @xtl for keeping the UI responsive use asynchrony. `await Task.WhenAll(...)` instead of `Task.WaitAll(...)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias didn't realise that about `StartNew`, I always use `Task.Run`. I'll update the answer.